# Dilemma with the data model using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema, data-modeling, database

I am working on an application on which we'll have users and videos.

It's a n-n relationship, a user can be related to several videos, and the same video can be related to several users.

I decided to go with mongoDB on the implementation, though I wasn't familiar with this technology at first, so I run into a problem regarding the document data model (in contraposition with the entity-relation data model).

In this application I'll need to access frequently the videos that are somehow related to a certain user. From this point of view, it would be logical to embed the document 'video' in the document 'user'.

But, I will also need frequent access to video collections, regardless of the users related to them. From this point of view, it seems the data model would be better designed if the the users related to the video were embedded inside its document.

Both designs make sense, and solve a problem, but make the remaining problem quite hard to solve; I would have to perform complex, inefficient queries to actually be able to get both functionalities with any of those two designs.

Right now I think the best decission would be to implement it the same way I would in a relational database (with two different documents for users and videos, and an intermediate document that allows me to know the relations between those two).

I'm really not sure that is the way this problem should be solved in mongoDB, so I would like to ask for advice regarding the data model design.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way: The most ideal solution for a problem with many n:n connections is a graph-oriented database. But the decision to use one should depend on the needs of the whole application, not just this one use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do both.

While redundancy should be avoided in a relational database, the same is not true for a document-oriented database. When you have no JOINs, you need to make sure that every common query can be fulfilled with documents from a single collection. Redundancy is usually the only way to achieve this.

The downside is that you now need two queries to update the relation, because both the `video` and the `user` document need to be updated. But that's a small price to pay, especially considering that updates are usually not as performance-critical as reads (you can perform them in the background while faking the result on the frontend for the user who requested the update).